# How to retrieve the definition behind statistics added to tables

Tags: sql-server-2008, statistics

In Sql Server, is there a way to progra-matically retrieve the definition of each STATISTICS added to table columns (and indexes). For both user added and system created indexes. There are many STATISTICS like '__WA_Sys_*' that are added by Sql Server.

I need to re-write some of them and add more. But there are too many to do them manually with Management Studio.

Thanks,
_UB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really understand what you want to do, but the SMO [Statistic class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.statistic.aspx) lets you create and manipulate statistics. From TSQL, there are several relevant views and procedures:  `sys.stats, sys.stats_columns, DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS, CREATE/UPDATE STATISTICS` etc.

If by 're-write' you mean 'update' then [UPDATE STATISTICS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187348.aspx) would be the place to start.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I figured out that there is no easy way to retrieve the definition of STATISTICS on all the tables. So, I wrote a script that uses `DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS`. I wish I had thought of `sys.Stats_Columns`. That would have made it much simpler. Oh well, hopefully this experience will help me remember it better.

Comment: I guess my reasoning was not clear. Some of the stats were added by previous DBA's but there is no code saved in Version Control. So I need to retrieve the each STATISTIC definition and add it to version control. Also, need to follow one standard in naming convention for all the objects in DB. Thank you for the comments,I see the gap in explaining my question earlier.

Comment: @UB. sp_helpstats is also useful.